# Which format should I use when adding a sound in XCode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, audio

I've seen some tutorials that use ".wav" format. But I want to know if I can use another format besides wav for my application.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use many audio format, you can choose any of the following types:

```
mp3, ima4, aif, lbc, m4a, caf
```

> The audio data must be in a format supported by Core Audio. For a list of supported formats, see [Using Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2) in [Multimedia Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767).